# Extract variable names from a binary?

Tags: c++, variables, disassembly

I would like to ask if is it possible to extract the exact variable names from a binary which is written by C++?

Comment: It depends a lot on the compiler and how the program was compiled with it. In some cases it's possible, in others possible partially, yet in others impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're lucky and on linux/unix, and the EXE is not stripped.  In that case, it contains the symbol table which contains the names of functions/methods and variables with static storage duration.

You can use `objdump` and `readelf` to inspect object files and executables.

Comment: @Adban: do note that this only gets certain names, not all the names.  All the names is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to extract the names of local variables from a C++ DLL or EXE.  This type of information is generally stored in the associated PDB.

Comment: ...when they're produced by Microsoft Visual C/C++.

Comment: @Alex which compiler embeds normal local names into the DLL / EXE?

Comment: I haven't researched this question for a while. I don't know. I think gcc does it to some extent. My comment was about the `.pdb` symbol files produced by MSVC++. I don't think there's any other compiler producing `PDBs`.

Comment: I think mingw can generate PE/COFF debugging symbols, stored inside the PE file (i.e. EXE/DLL)

Comment: @JaredPar GCC does this when you embedded debug information. You can read variable names and variable types. Forget M$ compilers.